# How do I convert string to decimal?

Tags: c#

I have this textbox that accepts numbers, commas, and periods.

Let's say this textbox contains input `14,500.00`

I tried to convert this number to decimal with `Convert.ToDecimal(textbox.text)` but it's not working. `Convert.ToDecimal()` to textboxes that contain input that has the format `XXXX.DD` are converted to decimal but input with format `X,XXX.DD` or any input with a thousand separator results to error:

> `Input string was not in correct format`

Is `Convert.ToDecimal()` appropriate in this case?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

[image]

Here is the form. If I click 'Add', the product of 'Price' and 'Quantity' should be displayed as 'Amount' in the datagridview.

The syntax in the 'Add' button includes:

```
DataRow dr;
dr = dsDetail.Tables["SalesOrderDetails"].NewRow();
dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSellingPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
```

The `Amount` field in my `SalesOrderDetails` table has the datatype `decimal(18,2)`

Comment: What is your culture?

Comment: @SonerGönül How can I determine the culture?

Comment: You can use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property the culture you are using. This property uses your _Regional and Language Options_ in your windows machine.

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced in this Culture stuff and I'm very sorry for asking this but where can I find that CultureInfo.CurrentCulture? Is it something I code somewhere in my project? or is it something i can find in the property window of my project? @SonerGönül.. Thanks for your help and I'll understand if you don't want to answer this question but i'll greatly appreciate it if you do.

Comment: @LeonardCupat Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what the txt values are when that are parsed?  and have you tried using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: @DStanley I have. When i the 'txtSellingPrice.text' shows the value that i have inputted. so as the

Answer (score 11):

You can force a culture and use `decimal.Parse`

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse("14,500.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 14500
```

> Is Convert.ToDecimal() appropriate in this case?

Yes, you could also continue to use `Convert.ToDecimal` if you want:

```
d = Convert.ToDecimal("14,500.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It is not working. I tried decimal.Parse and Convert.ToDecimal. I've done everything in your suggestion but it still produces the same error. Is it possible that the problem is coming from the textbox itself? or some datatype mismatch in the database that I'm using?

Answer (score 4):

I would give decimal.TryParse a go

```
decimal d;
if(decimal.TryParse(textbox.Text, out d))
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're using a culture that defines `.` as the *thousands* separator and `,` as the *decimal* separator.  If you want to force `,` and `.` as the thousands and decimal separators, respectively then use:

```
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(textbox.text,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Is Convert.ToDecimal() appropriate in this case?

It's fine - the main difference is it supports more types than `decimal.Parse`, which only supports `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @matt_lethargic, but offer a more complete solution. Tested with XUnit :)

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("en-US","44.00")]
[InlineData("es-PE", "44,00")]
[InlineData("es-PE", "44.00")]
[InlineData("es-PE", "0.01E-15")]
[InlineData("es-PE", "0,01E-15")]
public void ParsesDeciaml(string culture, string dec)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
    decimal d;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(dec, out d)
        && !decimal.TryParse(
                dec,
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                out d
            )
        && !decimal.TryParse(
                dec,
                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                out d
            )
    ) Assert.False(true, dec);

}
```

That way you can capture values with exponential formats.